# Transparency for gnome-terminal not working in awesome wm

Tags: awesome

I am new to awesome wm, when I change the transparency of the terminal from the preferences it turns black instead of becoming transparent I have no idea how to fix it. Not sure what code I should post here to help with the debugging, let me know if any data is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i figured out a way to get it working.

```
sudo apt-get install compton
```

and in the rc.lua file add

```
{ rule = { class = "x-terminal-emulator" },
        properties = { opacity = 0.75 } },
```

into the

```
awful.rules.rules
```

variable

and at the bottom of the rc.lua file add:

```
awful.util.spawn("compton")
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome WM doesn't have its own compositor which is required to handle transparency, shadows etc. You need to install a standalone compositor (e.g. `compton` for xorg).

Comment: Can you add some instructions on how to install and enable `compton`?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Compton/ or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compton

Comment: Thanks for the links, but could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1187853/edit) your answer to add the basic steps to install and enable `compton` and keep the links as reference? That way your answer will remain valid even if the links stop working. Also, this will make your answer more complete and it's more likely to get some upvotes. If you edit your answer, just ping me using @user3140225 and I will upvote it.